# Building Blocks not appearing after upgrade to Word 2013

Tags: ms-word, vsto

I have a document-level (dotx) customization, with a custom ribbon, and one of the controls in that ribbon is this:

```
<gallery idMso="CustomGallery1" label="Building Blocks" size="large" />
```

The only other part that makes this work is the creation of entries under `Custom1` in the Building Blocks Organizer. In Word 2010, this would show all the building blocks under the `Custom1` category. In Word 2013, it shows the name of each building block briefly, and then all of them are removed and the list is empty:

[image: Empty gallery of Custom1 building blocks]

The building blocks themselves all contain either a document property or document variable.

I have tried the following to resolve this but without success:

- Ensured that they are still present by opening the template outside of Visual Studio; they are.
- Upgraded the template to the 2013 dotx format.
- Re-created the building blocks.
- Re-created the entire dotx file, and then re-created the building blocks.

I also tried using other ribbon IDs, they are empty too (they do all have entries) but they display it differently:

[image: Empty gallery of Autotext building blocks]

There should be four entries there, they exist in my Normal.dotm. The last two controls there, for equations and content controls, do work, except the content control that is inserted displays similar behavior as the Autotext gallery:

[image: Empty gallery of Content control building blocks]

I don't know what should be shown in this case but I doubt it's nothing.

Right now I'm assuming that this is just a broken feature in 2013 and will have to replace it with something else. Does anyone know anything to the contrary?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it is a broken feature, after some struggle, I did get to understand how to use it:

The gallery button in the "toolbar" of a newly added Building Block Gallery Content Control  indeed seems empty at first, because it is set to list QuickParts. You have to change it in the properties of the control so that it lists the content of the AutoText Gallery instead (or any other Gallery of Building Blocks you'd like). To do so, either directly click on the Properties button in the Developper tab while the control is selected, or switch to Design Mode so that the Properties appears in the context menu (right-click on the control):

AutoText is "Insertion automatique" in French, the rest you can guess ;)

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks, that's interesting and does add some missing contextual information that was apparently staring me in the face.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I could find, it's just a broken feature. There's also a ridiculous memory leak the first time you [do a Find and add fields during that find](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/665c344c-1e32-468f-8862-a3220047b831/word-2013-uses-far-too-much-memory-when-adding-fields-runs-out?forum=vsto).